# SQL Server 2012 Install or add Full-text search

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, full-text-search

I am working in SQL Server 2012, and would like to use the CONTAINS() function only it seems I need to have full-text search enabled for to be able to use it. How do I enable/install this feature to an existing SQL Server 2012 install? What I need are steps please as I am yet to find the steps on going about this.

Comment: This question doesn't seem off topic to me. "How to use the `CONTAINS()` function" would be a fine question. The answer is to add full-text search. The next question is "How to add full text search", which seems quite on topic here.

Answer (score 56):

You can add full text to an existing instance **by changing the SQL Server program in Programs and Features**. Follow the steps below. You might need the original disk or ISO for the installation to complete. (Per HotN's comment: If you have SQL Server Express, make sure it is SQL Server Express *With Advanced Services*.)

Directions:

1. Open the Programs and Features control panel.
2. Select Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and click Change.
3. When prompted to Add/Repair/Remove, select Add.
4. Advance through the wizard until the Feature Selection screen. Then select Full-Text Search.

[image: Step 1] 
[image: Step 2]

[image]

5. On the Installation Type screen, select the appropriate SQL Server instance.
6. Advance through the rest of the wizard.

Source (with screenshots): http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/adding-sql-full-text-search-to-an-existing-sql-server/5546

Comment: I had this problem with SQL Server 2014 Express and the Full-Text Search option didn't exist in the installer wizard. I found that I needed SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services in order to get the full-text search option.

Comment: It worth mentioning that adding this feature to SQL Server 2012 will restart the instance, and unfortunately it will at no point notify you about this

Answer (score 1):

I think below link might help you -

http://svenaelterman.wordpress.com/2012/04/14/step-by-step-enabling-semantic-search-on-sql-server-2012/

Comment: Only steps 1 & 4 are relevant. The rest has to do with installing semantic search on top of full text.