# How to turn on Full-Text Search support

Tags: c++, sql-server-2012, odbc

I did install MS SQL Server 2012 Express Edition. It did install fine.

Now I'm trying to connect to it from the C++ program and get the information about it. Unfortunately doing so, I am getting the error "Full Text Search is not installed" error.

I tried to Google and all people suggest to try to run the installer, and in the "Features" page there will be an option to turn this feature on.

However, for some reason this feature is not present on this page.

So, is there anything I can do to overcome this error?

I have an "Express Edition SP1".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this post here: [SQL Server 2012 Install or add Full-text search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525106/sql-server-2012-install-or-add-full-text-search)

You will need the `SQL Server 2014 Express with Advanced Services` (see the comment from HotN). I think this are the setup files named something like `SQLEXPRADV_XY`